# IOS devices doesnt load html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I have html 5 canvas on my page, I throw images into it with javascript and I make them play with scroll. While it works smoothly on android devices and desktop devices, only white screen comes up on iphones, what could be the reason for this?

Html

```html
<section class="anvideo">
      <canvas id="hero-lightpass" />
</section>
```

Javascript

```js
var image = document.getElementById("canvasImage");
var mobileImage = document.getElementById("canvasMobileImage");
var imageWidth = image.width;
var imageHeight = image.height;
console.log(imageWidth + " - " + imageHeight);

const canvas = document.getElementById("hero-lightpass");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = imageWidth;
canvas.height = imageHeight;
image.style.display = "none";
mobileImage.style.display = "none";


const frameCount = 64;
const currentFrame = index => (
    `/images/${(index + 1).toString().padStart(3, '0')}.png`
);

const images = []
const airpods = {
    frame: 0
};

for (let i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = currentFrame(i);
    images.push(img);
}

gsap
    .timeline({
        onUpdate: render,
        scrollTrigger: {
            trigger: ".scroll-sequence__container",
            scrub: 1,
            start: "top top",
            end: "center",
        }
    })

    .to(
        airpods,
        {
            frame: frameCount - 1,
            snap: "frame",
            ease: "none",
            duration: 3
        },
        0
    )

images[0].onload = render;

function render() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(images[airpods.frame], 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Comment: Your do not check if the images have loaded. You can use `Image.complete` to test if the load is complete (loaded or error).  eg `if (images[airpods.frame].complete) { context.drawImage(images[airpods.frame], 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); }` Note that `complete` will also be true if the load failed. Or use the image on load event and wait for all images to load before starting the animation. On different devices the load time can vary due to how and if images are stored in the browser cache.

Comment: @Blindman67 i have figured out the error, on ios devices the render function does not trigger at all and i couldn't figure out why or how to make it work.